# What URL do I post to for Live Search SOAP service?

Tags: web-services, soap, search-engine, windows-live

Its possible I am just really really thick. However, looking over the SDK for the live search (MSN search) that uses SOAP, doesn't tell me what URL the service is at?? I can download SDKs for C# or VB which probably encapsulate, but that doesn't help me (I am using ruby).

http://search.live.com/developer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you need is: http://soap.search.live.com/webservices.asmx

Additional info on various tools you could use to discover endpoints from WSDL:

If you have VS, you can discover the endpoint by adding a Web Service Reference to a C# console project and then opening the app.config file and looking for the `<endpoint>` element.

To add the Web Service Reference for the Live Search web service, point the wizard to the WSDL at http://soap.search.live.com/webservices.asmx?wsdl.

Alternatively, you can use the svcutil.exe tool from .Net 3.0 to generate C# client wrapper and a .config file from the WSDL. Again, you are interested in the `<endpoint>` from the generate config.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I just wanted to give you more info on how you could find out the endpoint if you had VS.

In any case, you have the URL you were looking for. :-)